# Correct way to manage threads when processing a queue

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-4.5

I've got a queue (actually 3 different queues but I don't believe that will make a difference). The queue contains discrete units of work.

I have a `QueueManager` which spawns a new thread and returns. The new thread looks at the queue, gets a piece of work and then  spawns a new thread to process it.

I obviously want a limit on the number of concurrent threads and don't see any reason not to reuse a thread once it's finished the job.

Some of the jobs will take a while to run (minutes/hours) and I've read that the `ThreadPool` is not a good option for anything that takes more than a few seconds.

Effectively, I want to implement the ThreadPool but with a little more control.

So... What's the standard, best-practice way to achieve this?

It seems I need to (assuming the queue length > `MaxThreadCount`)

- Create new jobs until I hit `MaxThreadCount`
- Wait until any thread completes
- Get the next job from the queue and assign it to the thread
- Repeat
- If the queue empties, sleep for a length of time and then re-check

(The queue in this case is in a database so no event when items are added - I assume I'll just have to poll)

A lot of the jobs involve retrieving pages from remote sites/APIs, often repeatedly. As such, I believe I'd benefit from having considerably more threads than cores (as most of them will be waiting for the network). As such, I don't *believe* `WaitHandle` is appropriate as it has a 64-Thread limit.

This is obviously a pretty common pattern so I assume there must be a well-established way of implementing it?

If someone could point me at a good example, the would be excellent.

Comment: Agree with TPL answer. +1  If the bottleneck is retrieving remote data can you cache any?  Are you retrieving the same data repeatedly?

Comment: @Blam It's an interesting problem actually - I can cache stuff and in fact do so (at least all the results are stored in a Db) but most of the information is _never_ needed twice - and if it is required a second time, it's to see if the source has changed, so although I'm recording the output I probably won't ever refer to it again except for reporting purposes.

Comment: Probably not going to help in your case but one option is to also store the data in a dictionary so you are not hitting the db as much.

Comment: @Blam That's still a good idea, thanks - if Db performance is an issue, I could potentially use a dictionary as a cache in the same way CPUs do - which would at least minimise Db queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the TPL (Task Parallel Library).  It's designed for exactly this purpose.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Specifically, it sounds like you should create a [TaskFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321411) with a [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler) instance whose [MaximumConcurrencyLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.maximumconcurrencylevel) has been set to the number of threads that you want.  Then instead of putting your work items in a queue, call [TaskFactory.StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439).  It will handle the queueing of work for you.

Comment: That raises a second point which I didn't think applied - I was planning to use my `QueueManager` to update the database as each job completed and store results. I'm using EF and multi-threading EF is a pain. Using TPL, can I still have a single point of control to maintain the Db state or will I have to deal with it from within each thread?

Comment: You'll need to deal with multiple threads at some point.  You can have a single threaded task scheduler, but that's kind of defeating the purpose.